# EF 6 can't commit data to database from DGV

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have problem with saving data to database from grid. I don't know what i doing wrong so please help. This is my example code.

Code:

```
Imports System.Linq
 Public Class Grid1

  Public Property Year As Integer
  Public Property User As Integer

  End Class

   Public Class Form1

   public db as new databaseContext

   Dim Query As List(Of Grid1) = (From c In db.table Select New Grid1 With _
                                                      {_ 
                                                       .Year = c.Year, _
                                                       .User= c.User _ 
                                                      }).ToList

   dgv.DataSource = Query 

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Button1.Click

       Try
            db.SaveChanges()   '  i don't have any exception it just don't commit changes!

       Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString, ex.Message)
       End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: what data are you expecting to save to the database? you read the data from `db.table`, put it in a `New` list, then bind that list to the datagrid.  you aren't changing the database values, you are only changing the copy in your list.

Comment: Ok, but how can i save that copy to database?

Comment: what class is `db.table`?

Comment: It is table from database. It have two columns Year and User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Clasies is correct, you are not binding to anything that is connected to the database. You need to bind to Entity instances. Try something like:

```
dgv.DataSource = New ObservableCollection(Of table)(db.table.ToList())
```

EDIT:
I have added a basic [sample project to GitHub](https://github.com/crowcoder/EF6DataGridView) with a working EF6 DataGridView CRUD application.

Comment: i download your example code and i get this message:  Local {"The property 'Number' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. "} System.InvalidOperationException
How can i avoid this? I need to change key column also

Comment: There is no Number property in my code. So you are modifying it for your database? There is no way I can tell what your problem is with this information. Did it work for you before you changed it?

Comment: Yes it is my mistake. Now, how can i use where clauses.
        ctx.FruitDbSet.Load()  

        
        Dim flist = ctx.FruitDbSet.Local.ToBindingList()   'HOW CAN I IMPLEMENT THIS where x=> x.column = 1)   and then bind to grid.

Comment: like this: ctx.FruitDbSet.Local.Where(Function(x) x.Equals(1)).ToBindingList() or... ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73075/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-dejan).